# NestJS Typescript error when use forwardRef

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to use a provider into another provider within the same module.
[The Circular doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) is suggesting to use `forwardRef` function. However, in my module, it shows the below error:

```
Type 'ForwardReference<any>' is not assignable to type 'Provider<any>'.
  Type 'ForwardReference<any>' is not assignable to type 'ExistingProvider<any>'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Here is my module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    forwardRef(() => CartItemService),
    forwardRef(() => CartService),
    CartResolver,
    CartItemResolver,
    ,
    CartModel,
  ],
  exports: [CartService, CartItemService],
})
export class CartModule {}
```

And here is the gist of my provider

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(KNEX_CONNECTION) private readonly knex,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CartItemService))
    private readonly cartItem: CartItemService,
     ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `forwardRef` function should be used in the `imports` list, not in the `providers`, see [example in documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#module-forward-reference).

Also, you should either use a ModuleRef approach or a forwardRef approach, not both.

I suggest you try and implement the example in the documentation to determine how to implement it in your code.

Your module should be something like this:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    CartItemService,
    CartService,
    CartResolver,
    CartItemResolver,
    CartModel,
  ],
  exports: [CartService, CartItemService] //only if this module is imported by other modules
})
export class CartModule {}
```

The service as you did above is fine:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  constructor (
    @Inject(KNEX_CONNECTION) private readonly knex,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CartItemService)) private readonly cartItem: CartItemService,
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: But there is an example `@Inject(forwardRef(() => CommonService))` in providers.  Right now even if I use something like above I have the below error `Please make sure that the argument CartItemService at index [1] is available in the CartService context.`

Comment: I expect this code to work. Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong `@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(KNEX_CONNECTION) private readonly knex,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CartItemService))
    private readonly cartItem: CartItemService,
  ) {}`